# rootline not working with TYPO3 4.5 menus

Tags: menu, typo3

I'm having problems with TYPO3.  I have been using it for quite a few years, since version 3.8 but this is my first site using version 4.5 and I am having problems with the menus and the rootline.
I believe it is related to how the rootline is created. using the code below for the breadcrumb/path type of menu only the current page is displayed. The menu only displays `page X` using example and code below when in page X and it should be

`home > section 1 > sb a > page X`

```
home
--- section 1
------- sub A
---------- page X
--- section 2
```

Also when displaying menus the ACT state isn't being properly activated. As I understand every page in the path/rootline should activate the ACT state and it is not happening with code below.
Has any thing changed in this version?
I have used both piece of codes in many sites up to now in version 4.5

codes

```
temp.breadcrumbs = HMENU
temp.breadcrumbs.special = rootline
#temp.breadcrumbs.includeNotInMenu = 1
#temp.breadcrumbs.special.range= -2 | -1
temp.breadcrumbs.special.range = 0
temp.breadcrumbs.1= TMENU
temp.breadcrumbs.1.noBlur = 1
temp.breadcrumbs.1.NO.allWrap= |&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp; |*||*|   |

## with and without line   ... special.range   ...

.....
....

temp.topmenu.1 {
   wrap = <ul>|</ul>
   # NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>  
  expAll = 1   
   NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
   # Enable active state and set properties:
   ACT = 1
   ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current-menu-item">|</li>     
}
temp.topmenu.2 = TMENU
temp.topmenu.2.noBlur = 1
temp.topmenu.2 {
   wrap = <ul class="sub-menu">|</ul>
   NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>  
   # Enable active state and set properties:
   ACT = 1
   ACT.linkWrap =  <li class="active">|</li>
   #ACT.allWrap = <li class="selected">|</li>
   #ACT.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
}
```

thanks

Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

The range is supposed to be defined as **[begin-level] | [end-level]** so try:

```
temp.breadcrumbs.special.range = 0|-1
```

...or...

```
temp.breadcrumbs.special.range = 1|-1
```

- **-1** means current page.
- **-2** means the page one level up from the current page.

**NOTE:** You should probably set `temp.breadcrumbs.includeNotInMenu = 1` because usually you would like to have all the pages in the breadcrumbs (as the structure that breadcrumbs represent wouldn't otherwise make sense), that is including those that you don't want to appear in other menus.

Answer (score 0):

as cascaval wrote it's quite common to declare begin and end levels, anyway 0 value is aceptable too, as written in doc for `entryLevel`

> Default is "0" which gives us a menu of the very first pages on the site.

Probably you put some TypoScript on the `page X` which has `Rootlevel` field checked, so it avoids traversing the tree up-side. I examined your sample code on first implementation I had available and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Typo3 6.2.14 and finally found a solution.
After clearing "Template on Next Level" rootline worked perfectly.

Reason:

- the root template was referenced in root templates "Template on Next
  Level".

Solution:

- edit root template
- switch to tabfolder "Options"
- clear field "Template on Next Level"